# Preserve scroll position on DOM update in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a chat application which loads the recent chat messages and store them in `messages` array. Previous chat history is loaded on scroll and will be added to the beginning of `messages` array. I need to preserve the scroll position when history is loaded

```
//chat.vue
<div ref="chatHistory" @scroll="fetchHistory">
    <div v-for="item in messages" :key="item.id">
        <span>{{item.body}}</span>              
    </div>
</div>
```

In `fetchHistory` method, I add the old messages to beginning of `messages` array

```
fetchHistory(){
    if(this.$refs.messageHistory.scrollTop == 0){
        var vm = this
        this.currentPage.prevPage().then(paginator => {
            vm.messages.unshift(...paginator.messages)
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subtract initial height from final height in `nextTick()` function and update scroll position

```
fetchHistory(){
    if(this.$refs.messageHistory.scrollTop == 0){
        var initialHeight = this.$refs.messageHistory.scrollHeight
        var vm = this
        this.currentPage.prevPage().then(paginator => {
            vm.messages.unshift(...paginator.messages)
            vm.$nextTick(() => {
              vm.$refs.messageHistory.scrollTop = vm.$refs.messageHistory.scrollHeight - initialHeight
            })
        });
    }
}
```