# vue infinite load duplicate content issue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-infinite-loading

i install vue infinite loading for my chat app (backend laravel), everything is work now but if data respone from server contain something like a image or file, it seem to be load again and again like my image highlight bellow, correct the pic is load just one.
anyone can help with this issue? thanks!

```js
infiniteHandler($state) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                 axios.get('/messages', {
                        params: {
                            page: this.page,
                            room_id:this.user[0].shop_id === 0?this.user[0].id : this.user[0].shop_id
                        },
                    }).then(({ data }) => {


                        if (data.data.length) {
                            this.page += 1;
                            this.messages.unshift(...data.data.reverse());

                            $state.loaded();
                        } else {
                            $state.complete();
                        }
                    });
                }, 200);
            },
```

```html
    <div class="card-body" style="overflow: auto; height: 60vh; position: relative;" ref="card" @scroll="onScroll" >
  <infinite-loading direction="top" @infinite="infiniteHandler">    </infinite-loading>
  <div class="media"  v-for="(message, $index ) in messages" :key="$index">

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set a different `:key` in your `v-for`**. This is important for Vue to know which element is already rendered, and which should be re-rendered.

I don't know what your data looks like but you should have a uniq id for every items, or a name...

Using the index on dynamic lists will likely cause unecessary re-renders.

```html
<div
  class="media"
  v-for="message in messages"
  :key="message.id"
>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i also do this the image load one time but the scroll bar work incorect, it scroll to some position with no caculate position like normal of infinite loading

Comment: may be vue infinite loading using :key="index" to caculate the scroll bar position when load more data, but it also caught my problem

Comment: I feel like this has nothing to deal with the `vue-infinite-loading` component. I think it's just an `Intersection observer` with a loading spin. Try to replace it by a simple button that fetch new data and see if it fixes your problem?

Answer (score 0):

i remove vue-infinite-loading and end up with this solution [Preserve scroll position on DOM update in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765451/preserve-scroll-position-on-dom-update-in-vue-js) . everything work fine now!